# Estimating the chance

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

Suppose that in a day, a casino receives 2500 bets on a certain color(red or black) on one particular roulette wheel. Each bet is only a dollar bet. The house(casino) has 20 in 38 chances to win. Estimate the chance that the house will win at least 100 dollars. Write your answer as a decimal

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please show any own attempts you've made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of dollars won by the house.

We know that $X \sim B\left(2500,\dfrac{10}{19}\right)$.

We can estimate it by $N(1316,623)$.

So, the required probability (using continuity correction):

$\begin{array}{cl}
=&P(X \ge 99.5) \\
=&P\left(Z \ge \dfrac{99.5-1316}{623} \right) \\
=&P\left(Z \ge -1.9526 \right) \\
=&P\left(Z \le 1.9526 \right) \\
=&0.9744
\end{array}$